# How do I get correct currency data to stripe.com from my CiviCRM transactions

Tags: civicontribute, contributions, payment-processor, contribution-page, currency

Background: Wordpress site, CiviCRM 4.6.x, Stripe extension version 1.9.1 is reported, and the directory in my extensions folder is called com.drastikbydesign.stripe-4.6-dev (installed in June/July).

Civi is configured with GBP as the default currency, and GBP, USD and EUR are all set as available currencies. We have - at present - three contribution pages, one for each of the three currencies, and the currency is set in the configuration for each page.

CiviCRM is recording the transaction in the correct currency (USD). Stripe is recording the transaction, but is recording it in GBP. This is causing a major issue as you might expect. For example, we have a user who has donated USD20. CiviCRM tells us they have donated USD20, but Stripe has read this as GBP20, and taken USD31.64 from the user's credit card. Not good.

Looking at the events and logs data in the Stripe dashboard I can see that 'gbp' is being given everywhere as the currency.

I don't know if this is a bug in this extension or more generally in CiviCRM, but my guess - and it is a guess - is that the currency data is being taken from the default currency rather than from the currency that is set for the specific contribution page.

Here's a link to the issue in the extension repo: https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/issues/91

Comment: hi, did you manage to fix the issue -

Answer (score 2):

It transpired that the error was due to the fact that the affected transactions were recurring payments, and the stripe extension did not pass currency data to stripe.com. So, in my use case, a user has submitted a recurring payment in GBP, and a subsequent user has attempted to submit the same payment in terms of amount and frequency, but in USD. As the currency was not being included in the payment plan data being submitted, stripe.com assumes that the plan is in GBP, because that is how the plan was originally defined, and so takes the payment in GBP.

Having liaised with the extension developer, this issue has since been addressed and I'm aiming to test the changes as soon as possible to see if it has resolved the issue.